# how to assign keyboard shortcut to buried command?

Tags: macos, keyboard, pdf, google-chrome, printing

In Chrome, if I do <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to print, and click Print Using System Dialog, then click on the PDF dropdown button, I get a command called Save PDF to DEVONthink Pro.

In System Preferences > Keyboard > App Shortcuts, I created a shortcut named Save PDF to DEVONthink Pro. But pressing that keystroke has no effect.

How do can I call this command using a single keystroke?

Comment: You can do this using AppleScript + FastScripts. I could provide the code but I don't get where you have your drop-down button.

Comment: Hmm. When I Print using system dialog, then click on `PDF`, I get other options.

Comment: Ok I see.  If no one answers this and if OP is patient, OP will get answer tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code :

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate

    tell window 1 to tell active tab to print
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
        delay 1
        tell window "Print"
            click menu button "PDF"
            delay 1
            try
                click menu item # of menu of menu button "PDF"
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Just replace the `#`with the index of your script in the menu.  (FYI : 1 is `Open PDF in Preview`, 8 is `Save PDF via Messages`